# How can I efficiently run groupby() over subsets of a dataframe to avoid MemoryError

Tags: python, pandas, memory

I have a decent sized dataframe (roughly: `df.shape = (4000000, 2000)`) that I want to use `.groupby().max()` on. Unfortunately, neither my laptop nor the server I have access to can do this without throwing a MemoryError (The laptop has 16G of RAM, the server has 64.) This is likely due to the datatypes in a lot of the columns. Right now, I'm considering those are fixed and immutable (many, many dates, large integers, etc), though perhaps that could be part of the solution.

The command I would like is simply `new_df = df.groupby('KEY').max()`.

What is the most efficient way to break down this problem to prevent running into memory problems? Some things I've tried, to varying success:

1. Break the `df` into subsets and run `.groupby().max` on those subsets, then concatenating. Issue: the size of the full `df` can vary, and is likely to grow. I'm not sure the best way to break the `df` apart so that the subsets are definitely not going to throw the MemoryError.
2. Include a subset set of columns on which to run the `.groupby()` in a new `df`, then merge this with the original. Issue: the number of columns in this subset can vary (much smaller or larger than current), though the names of the columns all include the prefix `ind_`.
3. Look for out-of-memory management tools. As of yet, I've not found anything useful.

Thanks for any insight or help you can provide.

**EDIT TO ADD INFO**

The data is for a predictive modeling exercise, and the number of columns stems from making binary variables from a column of discrete (non-continuous/categorical) values. The `df` will grow in column size if another column of values goes through the same process. Also, data is originally pulled from a SQL query; the set of items the query finds is likely to grow over time, meaning both the number of rows will grow, and (since the number of distinct values in one or more columns may grow, so will the number of columns after making binary indicator variables). The data pulled goes through extensive transformation, and gets merged with other datasets, making it implausible to run the grouping in the database itself.

There are repeated observations by `KEY`, which have the the same value except for the column I turn into indicators (this is just to show shape/value samples: actual df has dates, integers 16 digits or longer, etc):

```
KEY    Col1  Col2   Col3
 A      1    blue   car
 A      1    blue   bike
 A      1    blue   train
 B      2    green  car
 B      2    green  plane
 B      2    green  bike
```

This should become, with dummied Col3:

```
KEY    Col1  Col2   ind_car ind_bike ind_train ind_plane
 A      1    blue      1        1        1         0
 B      2    green     1        1        0         1
```

So the `.groupby('KEY')` gets me the groups, and the .max() gets the new indicator columns with the right values. I know the `.max()' process might be bogged down by getting a "max" for a string or date column.

Comment: Are you able to form the groups successfully? As is, if you run `grouped = df.groupby('KEY')` does it complete without throwing memory error? If yes, then you can simply compute max on a subset of groups, and store the result on disk, appending to the file as you move along the groups. The issue seems to be insufficient memory to store both the df and the max results together.

Comment: You also say that your `df` is likely to grow. How are you creating the `df`? Are you reading a set of csv files, scraping from the web, or querying from a database? If it is csv or database, you can chunk your `df` such that you will only have manageable size chunks in memory at any given time. I don't use web services, so I don't know how that would work. Well, if you are reading from a database, perform the groupby in the database itself!

Comment: Added info above. Hope it helps to clarify. Thanks!